# Parallel.ForEach dynamic action array

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, action, parallel.foreach

Currently, I'm invoking an array of actions in parallel (the array data originates from a DB call). When all of the actions are finished, the array is rebuilt and newly accumulated actions are invoked. The problem is that long running actions at the tail end cause the whole process to take too long.

Ideally, as the array empties of actions, it's rebuilt on the fly so that the maximum number of actions can always run at once. I was hoping there was a way to do this with `Parallel.Foreach` by checking the action array count and rebuilding it by calling a sub on the fly. This is the code I'm using now:

```
Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, actionsArray);
```

Any tips on how to use `Parallel.Foreach` in the way I described (or some other methodology)? This code seems to be close to what I want, but it's beyond my skill to adapt it:

```
public static void ParallelWhileNotEmpty<T>(
IEnumerable<T> initialValues,
Action<T, Action<T>> body)
    {
        var from = new ConcurrentQueue<T>(initialValues);
        while (!from.IsEmpty)
        {
            var to = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
            Action<T> addMethod = to.Enqueue;
            Parallel.ForEach(from, v => body(v, addMethod));
            from = to;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you actually using an array or do you mean a List? And what does the basic structure of your code look like right now?

Comment: Worth to look at [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx).